# Wrong page number for appendix in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm preparing my thesis, but unfortunately the page number of the Appendices does not appear correctly in my table of contents. Here is part of my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\begin{document}

\begin{KeepFromToc}
\tableofcontents \cleardoublepage
\end{KeepFromToc}

\chapter{Introduction}
This is chapter 1.

\appendix
\part*{Appendices}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Appendices} 

\chapter{Appendix A1}
This is A1.

\end{document}
```

When you compile this code, in the table of contents it says that "Appendices" are on p. 7, but they are on p. 5. Any suggestions on how to fix this are very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `memoir` class, the following command will add `\part*` headings to the table of contents.

```
\renewcommand\mempartstarinfo[1]{\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}}
```

If you add it to your preamble, it will be done consistently for all unnumbered parts. If you want to add just `Appendices` to the table of contents, add the definition immediately before the `\part*` and use braces to make the change local.

```
{\renewcommand\mempartstarinfo[1]{\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}}
 \part*{Appendices}%
}
```